# Cant interact with funds. Serious help needed

Tags: transactions, wallet

New Keystone Wallet. Pushed 1 transaction via Keystone QR code to the wallet over a month ago and could view it via OKX imported hardware wallet. Everything looked good, so I went to my Keystone wallet to send a 2nd transaction, but this time i decided to generate a new address, which I used the QR code to send.

The 2nd transaction was successful in its receipts. However, wasnt showing on OKX. I deleted my OKX wallet and readded it. Now I show only the 2nd transaction and I'm missing the first.

I have tried OKX Wallet, Blue Wallet and Sparrow Wallet. None of them show my first transaction. How is this even possible? On Sparrow I setup the gap lookup to 999 and still nothing was found.

Blue Wallet has a feature to look up an address, and manually entering in the address from the block explorer receipt, it doesn't locate the address. However, i plug the address from the 2nd transaction and it of course locates it.

I dont know if Keystone created a faulty address on the 1st transaction, but if it did, how was it originally able to view it via the OKX wallet? If I choose a "Watch-Only" account and manually plug in the 1st transaction's address, i do see my funds, but I cannot figure out how to interact with them, or why they are not reconciling with my 2nd transaction's funds.

Any help would be very appreciated!